# Determine JSONPath from char index

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonpath

Is it possible in C# to get the JSONPath from the char index position? i.e. imagine putting a text cursor within a JSON string, and wanting to know the JSONPath from that position.

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(@"{""items"":[{""item1"":""Something1""},{""item2"":""Something2""},{""item3"":""Something3""},{""item4"":""Something4""}]}}");

int charindex = 26;
string jsonpath = o.GetToken(charindex); // imaginary method call

jsonpath == "$.items[?(@.Item1 == 'Something1')]";
```

I've searched for a library or code snippet to help with no luck. What is the best approach? Would a regex be suitable?

Comment: It's not exactly what you want, but `JToken` explicitly implements the [`IJsonLineInfo`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_IJsonLineInfo.htm) interface.  If you [parse](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Parse_1.htm) the root `JToken` with [`new JsonLoadSettings { LineInfoHandling = LineInfoHandling.Load }`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JsonLoadSettings_LineInfoHandling.htm) then each token will remember its line number and position in the string.

Comment: And, given a `JToken`, you can get its path with [`token.Path`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Path.htm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think NewtonSoft's `JsonTextReader` can give you what you want, using the `Path`, `LineNumber` and `LinePosition` properties.

This code for example:

```
var s = @"
    {
        ""obj"": {
            ""foo"": ""bar""
        },
        ""arr"": [
            1,
            2,
            3
        ]
    }
";
using(var sr = new System.IO.StringReader(s))
{
    var r = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader(sr);
    while (r.Read())
        Console.WriteLine(r.LineNumber + ":" + r.LinePosition + " : " + r.Path);
}
```

will give the the following output:

```
2:5 : 
3:14 : obj
3:16 : obj
4:18 : obj.foo
4:24 : obj.foo
5:9 : obj
6:14 : arr
6:16 : arr
7:13 : arr[0]
8:13 : arr[1]
9:13 : arr[2]
10:9 : arr
11:5 :
```

But if you really want to work with only the char index, you might want to replace all newLines and carriageReturns in your json string into whitespaces, so everything is on one single line...

Now to getting the path of a specific place in your string is easy:

```
var charIndex = 48;
var s = @"
    {
        ""obj"": {
            ""foo"": ""bar""
        },
        ""arr"": [
            1,
            2,
            3
        ]
    }
";
s = s.Replace("\n", " ").Replace("\r", " ");
var path = "";
using(var sr = new System.IO.StringReader(s))
{
    var r = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader(sr);
    while (r.Read() && r.LinePosition <= charIndex )
        path = r.Path;
}
Console.WriteLine(path); // obj.foo
```

Comment: Fantastic answer, thank you! Gives me a helpful push in the right direction.